# Create mutliarch installable package for JavaFX application

Tags: maven, javafx

I use a 64-bit OS to develop a JavaFX application and use Maven to build my application with javafx-maven-plugin to generate an installation package. The resulting package contains only a 64-bit application. So, is there a way to create a multiarch installator or create a pair of x86 / x64 installators in one pass?

**UPD**
Could you provide an example of a targeted build-system based on maven? Is it needed to use differents OS or just differents JRE on OS x64? In last case how to build the pair of installers per one run? How to automatically add a suffix to application name to noting the architecture? Is it needed to use e.g. Jenkins, or it can be done with maven alone? Is there a some "classic" configuration of the targeted build-system? And more, is there some drawbacks to use 32-bit application on 64-bit OS? From my tests follows that 32-bit app (for my case) is slower on 32-bit OS than on 64-bit OS. But 32-bit and 64-bit application on 64-bit OS work equally.

Answer (score 0):

this is indended, because the underlying installers contain that information. There is no future where this can be provided, this was a JDK-bug once, but closed as "wont fix". As the javafx-maven-plugin uses the official `javapackager`-tooling, all benefits/drawbacks of that tooling is valid here too. This is even in the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1307236

You need a build-system per targeted architecture.

**EDIT:** regarding your updated question: you can only create windows-launchers/installers on windows-systems, you can only create linux-launchers/installers on linux-systems, and the same form mac. This means in order to get launchers/installers from the one project, you have to run the build on every platform, and two times each. One time you have to call it with 32bit JDK being installed, and the other time with 64bit JDK installed (might work on Windows to only have JAVA_HOME being set, as maven picks this up), it does not need any tool like Jenkins, but if you have it, just use it.

About the performance I can't say anything, this is out of scope and is bound to the JRE itself.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of that maven-plugin.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated the question with more questions following  your answer. Could you see it?

Comment: Updated my answer